# Creating my own Jekyll template for GitHub pages to make 100s of identical pages for similar projects

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

My GitHub org is github.com/Obrary (apologies for not putting the full url, but I don't have enough reputation points for that yet).  There, I have 100s of open designs for products.  Each is a project.  I want each to have a GitHub page for the project.

I created a simple GitHub page for one of the projects.  See http://obrary.github.io/Alex-Chair/.  The page is created so that I can add it to any projects gh-pages branch and it will work for the new project.  To see that in action, http://obrary.github.io/Alexey-Surfboard-Rack/.

Now I want to use this page across all of my open design projects.  As I said, there are 100s.  So I don't want to just copy and paste the files.  Is there a way to make a project that is the 'master template' for all of the projects that I want to associate it to?  I'd like to be able to edit the master and have the changes automatically reflected on all the GitHub pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's a challenge !

You already have 100's projects site structured on the same templates in 100's separate repositories and you want to share a common design.

#### Sharing common style-sheets

Just create a repository to host common stylesheets (eg: https://github.com/Obrary/styles. And from every gh-pages, just grab this stylessheets, you then can replicate styles over your entire networks.

#### Sharing common templates

If you want to share common templates, the only solution is to group all the projects sites under the same repository.
But here you loose the ability to offer the zip download, specific to every project, and the ability (I think) to allow contributor to work in a specific repository.

#### The ultimate solution

Having a central repository for templates and styles with a rake task that pushes updates to all the projects repositories. This will make Github pages regenerates automatically on every project. Cool!

Let's elaborate a little on this solution.

- You have a central repository for all common files needed in your
  projects sites. Those files are mainly `_includes`, `_layouts` and
  `_sass` folders.
- All your projects sites are based on this repository. Their pages,
  posts and static files can evolve independently from the central
  repository.
- Any time you're updating the central repository, a [webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) calls
  a script on a server. This script can be a rake task or a bash script
  or anything you're good at.
- The script simply copies files or pulls from central repository and
  then push to all projects sites.
- Github then will publish automatically.

Comment: Thanks David.  Makes sense.  Make a central project where I put common assets so that when they are updated, all the project pages benefit.  In the Ultimate Solution, what would the rake task look like?  I'm new to GitHub and just starting to figure things out.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain a little more the Ultimate solution.

Comment: Hmm.  

So I started with the first scenario - combine the shared element in a central repo.  I took the images and CSS from the public folder and moved them to https://github.com/Obrary/GH-Pages-Master-Designs/tree/gh-pages.  

I then updated the image and CSS links in https://github.com/Obrary/Alex-Chair/tree/gh-pages to point to the shared repo's files.  The images work fine.  But there's a problem with the CSS files not working as you can see at http://obrary.github.io/Alex-Chair/.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don not use files from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com` they're served slowly and with `text/plain` mime type. As you have a `gh-pages` branch, github generates a site with your ressources and they're served faster and with the right mime type eg : https://obrary.github.io/GH-Pages-Master-Designs/public/css/lanyon.css